# OpenCover with "release build"

Tags: opencover

Opencover works well with a debug version of my product.
When running with the "release version" it outputs "no results found" although the path to th release build pdbs (-targetdir) is correct.

My product is a dotnet 4.6.1 application written in C#

Is there a way to use OpenCover with release builds? Is something needed for the PDBs to be generated differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that wasn't it. 
I used OpenCover on a service using the service display name (in –target argument) instead of the service name.
It still identified the service and started it but apparently DID NOT INSTRUMENT IT (the service started very fast, no coverage results after service stopped)
When I used the service name as –target, the service started significantly slower (hence I guess was instrumented) and coverage results were obtained.